# How to gdb a core file with seg fault in centos 6.5?

Tags: c, linux

My program is multi thread. i got a core file and when i try to debug it i got this.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  memcpy () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S:91
91      movl    %ecx, (%rdi)
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install libssh2-1.8.0-2.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  memcpy () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S:91
#1  0x00007f981b342feb in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000025f1ef0 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000025edef0 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fff4b65a810 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000025cb800 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000025ccea0 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Why the bt infos are "???" Can i identify which thread and where case the seg fault?

Thank you.

Comment: You should compile your program with debug informations.

Comment: You are missing the debug symbols are used by gdb to print backtraces. You should compile your binary with `-g` flag. Also, try adding the debug info for the libssh2 with `set solib-search-path <path to shared non-absolute (relative) symbol files>`

Answer (score 1):

In order to run gdb and make the best use of it, firstly, you need to compile your source with the `-g or -ggdb3` option of `gcc` in the following way:

```
gcc -ggdb3 sample.c -o sample
```

After this you will get an executable or binary file which you can execute. Upon execution the program will generate a segfault and a coredump will be created. You can use this core file in the following way with `gdb` to obtain the backtrace:

```
gdb ./sample /path/to/core/file
```

You can even launch your program using gdb without actually executing it separately and generating the core file explicitly. If you want to do this, execute the following command:

```
gdb ./sample
```

Comment: thanks, actually i did it with ''CFLAGS += -g  -Wall' .

Comment: Yes that is the way to go while using the Makefile. If you found this answer useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "??" entries are where symbol translation failed. Stack walking – which produces the stack trace – can also fail. In that case you'll likely see a single valid frame, then a small number of bogus addresses. If symbols or stacks are too badly broken to make sense of the stack trace, then there are usually ways to fix it: installing debug info packages (giving gdb more symbols, and letting it do DWARF-based stack walks), or recompiling the software from source with frame pointers and debugging information (-fno-omit-frame-pointer -g).